# Searching for gender stereotype questionnaire specific to central europe

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, gender

Reviewing the literature there are several inventories to measure gender stereotype values. For example, to name but a few:

- the Adjective Check List (ACL; Williams & Bennett, 1975)
- the Sex-Role Stereotype Questionnaire (Rosenkrantz et al., 1968)
- the Personal Attributes Questionnaire (PAQ, Spence, Helmreich & Stapp, 1974; Runge et al., 1981)
- the Bem Sex Role Inventory (BSRI; Bem, 1974; Schneider-Düker & Kohler, 1988)
- the Modern Sexism Scale (Swim et al., 1995)
- the Ambivalent Sexism Inventory (Glick & Fiske, 1996)
- the Skala zur Messung der normativen Geschlechtsrollen-Orientierung (GRO-Skala; Krampen, 1979, 1983)

However, as can be clearly seen, these instruments are outdated, and they are often based on the Anglo-American culture.

**Can anyone help me out with a hint on a more contemporary gender stereotype questionnaire which refers to Germany or central Europe respectively?** An inventory already edited for computer administration would be ideal.

Comment: Rather than reposting a duplicate, you can edit your original question (as I did for you now), ever so slightly improving on it, or including new stuff you encountered in your search.